# Controller load error message after load and not after submit

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, web-applications

Try to figure out when I load my jsp page the error message is shown even if I do not submit the button. Can anyone advice how to show error message after submit the button. I post my code here for control.
Thanks in advance

LoginController

```
@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginServiceImpl;


    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView validUser(@ModelAttribute("person") PersonModel personModel) {

         ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView("login");
                 try
                {
                    boolean validUser = loginServiceImpl.isValidUser(personModel.getName(), personModel.getPassword());

                    //Zjistí zda-li je user přihlášen
                    if(validUser)
                        {
                         System.out.println("User Login Successful");

                         model.addObject("successMessage", personModel.getName());
                        }
                    else
                        {
                         System.out.println("Login wasn't Successful"); 
                         model.addObject("unsuccessmessage", "Invalid credentials!!");
                        }

                 }
               catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return model;
    }

}
```

JSP Page

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>


<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form id="loginForm" method="post" action="login" modelAttribute="person">  
               <form:label path="name">Login name:</form:label>
                <form:input id="name" name="name" path="name" /><br>
                <form:label path="password">Password</form:label>
                <form:password id="password" name="password" path="password" /><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

                <h2>${unsuccessMessage}</h2>
                <h2>${successMessage}</h2>

            </form:form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post the error message you are receiving?

Comment: I have not got any error. In my jsp code I have form and there I would like to show error message when user types bad username and password and then will show the error message. But the error message shows up after load the jsp page and I do not know how to fix it that the error message shows up after submit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve